# Can create directories, but not files via Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory in Android 11

Tags: android, android-11, android-storage

I am trying do some tests with `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` in Android 11.

**Question 1**: Why I can't create a new file but a new directory I can do?
**Question 2**: `canRead()` + `canWrite()` return true, but `createNewFile()` does not work, why?

(if null, if exists, ... checks are omitted for this example)

Get public movies dir:

```
fun getExternalPublicMoviesDir(): File? {
    val movies = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)
    try {
        movies.mkdirs()
        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState(movies) == Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) {
            return movies
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return null
}
```

Create files/folders:

```
val externalMoviesPath = getExternalPublicMoviesDir()
externalMoviesPath.canRead() //return true
externalMoviesPath.canWrite() //return true

val newDir = File(externalMoviesPath, "newDirTest")
newDir.mkdirs() //works

val newFile = File(externalMoviesPath, "newFileTest")
newFile.createNewFile() // <- java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
```

Exception:

```
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1008)
```

Just for completeness: In Android 10 code works when `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is granted.

**UPDATE**
When I use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)` instead of `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)`, `createNewFile` method is working.

Tested on real devices like Samsung, Pixel and on Android emulator.

Comment: Only call mkdirs() if the directory does not exist yet. And if you call mkdirs() check the return value as it might fail. Stop if false is returned

Comment: `Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED` External storage is always mounted so this check brings nothing. Only unreadable code.

Comment: `movies != null` Why would that suddenly be null?

Comment: `mkdirs()` contains test on exist. "External storage is always mounted" that's not true! Your answers don't help to solve the problem again. Please comment only if the comments help resolve the issue.

Comment: Reacting in a normal way to comments would help to solve your issue. You are spoiling it now. And again.

Answer (score 0):

You can user **FileProvider** with **Context.getExternalFilesDir(type)** where type can be directory etc... **DIRECTORY_MOVIES** from now and set path as `<external-files-path name="" path="/" />` in xml directory. For Further detail https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider

Comment: Path from `Context.getExternalFilesDir(type)` is "app's specific storage". Question was about `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`

Comment: Alternative to user it you can check 'Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory' is Deprecated in API level 29 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)

Comment: Yes method is deprecated. Do you know answers to both questions?

Comment: Yes, I have already implemented it through FileProvider.